# Error in unserialize(rx_model): read error

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, serialization, revoscaler

I've created a model in R, published into SQL Server table and validated the model by calling it into SQL Server. However, I am failing to execute model stored procedure in SQL server.

I get this error message:

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 2
A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
An external script error occurred: 
Error in unserialize(rx_model) : read error
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> unserialize

Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
Execution halted
```

Tried this;

```
model <- unserialize(rx_model);
```

or

```
model <- unserialize(as.raw(rx_model));
```

also tried;

```
model = unserialize(rx_model);
```

Still getting same error.

New to R/ML in SQL Server, help would be appreciated

Comment: What command triggered the error?

Comment: I used above commands to "unserialize" before using the model.m ie, First tried this: model <- unserialize(rx_model);. then again, model <- unserialize(as.raw(rx_model));. both are giving same errors